# Dynamic Workflow diagram creation in angular

Tags: angular, workflow, diagram

We have a requirement wherein we have to show the dynamic workflow diagram of a workflow, where each process has set of different task , user can perform a set of actions on each task like cancel a task, resume a task.

Which framework/library will be suitable to achieve this. I have found below libraries like flowchart.js, syncfusion, yfiles but performing action on each task under a main task seems to be not achievable.

Comment: This seems to be asking for a recommendation for a tool, which will likely lead to a closing of the question. However if you told us where exactly you ran into the problem and what you tried, we might be able to help. I am pretty confident that yFiles can do what you are trying to do, so with some more details regarding your problem, this could become a valid question for this place. Even though in the case of yFiles there is an official, professional support route available, too.

Comment: Sure, i am already doing a small POC on Yfiles, to try out the requirement which i am asking help here, would let you know with the problem if i face any. Thanks

Comment: I am able to achieve the layout as expected using hierarchical layout of Yfiles, need suggestion how to create a divider line in between the layers in hierarchical layout.  Like as in below layout to separate out the task at each layer
                        Parent Task1
 TASK1 -->   TASK2 -->    TASK3 -->   TASK4

-----------------------------------------------
                      Parent Task2